# How to access gridview data in a seperate button click event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

My requirement is I need to access the Grid view data in a button click event.
I have Grid view with name gvData and have button named Update. 
On click of update button I am saving data entered in the grid by user to DB.
Please suggest me in getting this done. Code snippets would be of great help.
I am populating the gridview on page load:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                DataTable dt;
                String SQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Class";


                string sConstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sConstr))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn))
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm))
                        {
                            dt = new DataTable();
                            da.Fill(dt);
                        }
                    }
                }

                gvMarks.DataSource = dt;
                gvMarks.DataBind();

            }
        }
<asp:GridView ID="gvMarks" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"/>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="One">

                        <ItemTemplate>

                            <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("One") %>'></asp:TextBox>

                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Two">

                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TWO") %>'></asp:TextBox>

                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Three">

                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtThree" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("THREE") %>'></asp:TextBox>


                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Four">

                        <ItemTemplate>

                            <asp:TextBox ID="txt4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FOUR") %>'></asp:TextBox>

                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FIVE">

                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFive" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FIVE") %>'></asp:TextBox>

                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SIX">

                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txt6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SIX") %>'></asp:TextBox>

                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpdae" runat="server" Text="Update Marks" OnClick="btnUpdae_Click" />


    protected void btnUpdae_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             //Need to acces the grid view rows and colums here
         }
```

Comment: Narrow the question to a specific issue. Some code would definitely promote an answer.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If nothing, then try researching first, trying something and if you still have issues come back here and see if we can help. Also, show code you've tried and what problems you've hit.

Comment: I am able to access the column names in the button click event abd i am not able to get the values of rows and columns.

Answer (score 1):

fetch row one by one by foreach or for loop and save the data.
[Click This to know more about save the gridview data to your database](http://forums.asp.net/t/1634013.aspx?Save%20entire%20Gridview%20data%20into%20Database)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
protected void btnUpdae_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            int rowIndex = 0;
            StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();
            if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
            {
                DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
                if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //extract the TextBox values
                        TextBox box1 = (TextBox)gvMarks.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("txt1");
                        TextBox box2 = (TextBox)gvMarks.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txt2");
                        TextBox box3 = (TextBox)gvMarks.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txt3");
                        TextBox box4 = (TextBox)gvMarks.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txt4");
                        TextBox box5 = (TextBox)gvMarks.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("txt5");
                        TextBox box6 = (TextBox)gvMarks.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("txt6");

                        //get the values from the TextBoxes
                        //then add it to the collections with a comma "," as the delimited values
                        sc.Add(box1.Text + "," + box2.Text + "," + box3.Text+ "," + box4.Text + "," + box5.Text+ "," + box6.Text);
                        rowIndex++;
                    }
                    //Call the method for executing inserts or update
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the following approach-

```
TextBox txt=(TextBox)gvMarks.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("txt1");
string txtOne= txt.Text;
```

You can use this with for loop and for all the text boxes. Then insert/update the data taken in string variable like txtOne(above used) into the table.Then bind the grid again. You can hit the following link for another solution.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1647616.aspx?Get%20Value%20of%20TextBox%20inside%20the%20GridView%20in%20c%20

I hope this can make your work done.